# Modify, remove or add data to hdf5 files with R

Tags: r, hdf5, hdf, rhdf5

I have a hdf5 file with several attributes, each attribute is either a matrix or an array. I would like to modify some of the attributes by adding or removing a column to the matrix. How can this be done?

I have tried with the rhdf5 library in R but I can't seem to find the right functions. It seems I can only use write functions but I can't overwrite. I was thinking the only way might be to dump the whole file, modify and save as a new file.

This is a sample of my file

```
a=H5Fopen("S-1500-01-01-000000-g01.h5")
a
HDF5 FILE
        name /
    filename 

                           name       otype  dclass         dim
0   AGB_CO                      H5I_DATASET FLOAT   411        
1   AGB_CUT                     H5I_DATASET FLOAT   17 x 11 x 1
2   AGB_GROWTH                  H5I_DATASET FLOAT   17 x 11 x 1
3   AGB_MORT                    H5I_DATASET FLOAT   17 x 11 x 1
4   AGB_PY                      H5I_DATASET FLOAT   17 x 11 x 1
5   AGB_SI                      H5I_DATASET FLOAT   17 x 11 x 1
6   AGE                         H5I_DATASET FLOAT   20         
7   AGRI_STOCKING_DENSITY       H5I_DATASET FLOAT   1          
8   AGRI_STOCKING_PFT           H5I_DATASET INTEGER 1
```

Comment: At the moment the only way to do this is to manually delete the object using hdfview and then add it in R after being modified.